# Filter records by virtual attribute rather than database field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using this function in my `User` model to populate a select box in a form:

```
def outstanding_invoices
  invoices.to_a.select { |invoice| invoice.balance < 0 }
end
```

The problem is that `balance` is not a database field but a method that calculates something.

So it takes an awful lot of SQL queries to generate the select box because the function above iterates over every single `invoice` that the `user` has.

Is there a faster way to generate the select box, ideally using one SQL query only?

A simple alternative would probably be storing the `balance` of each `invoice` in the database, but I am somehow reluctant to do that because I want to keep my database to a minimum.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Based on experience working with calculated money values, it makes sense in a lot of cases to store the calculated value along with the parameters used to calculate that value - that way you can run queries against the calculated value, but you also have traceability as to how the value was calculated.

In your invoice example, I recommend you implement an `after_save` callback in your `Payment` model. For example:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice

  def after_save
    invoice.update_balance
  end
end

class Invoice
  has_many :payments

  def self.with_open_balance
    where("current_balance > 0")
  end

  def update_balance
    update_attributes(:current_balance => balance)
  end

  def balance
    invoiced_amount - payments.sum(:amount)
  end
end
```

With this approach, you can now call `customer.invoices.with_open_balance` to get all the open invoices for that customer. Whenever a payment is saved, the invoice to which the payment belongs will recalculate its balance and store that calculated value within the same database transaction, ensuring consistency.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. Just trying to implement this. The `update_attributes` method causes a `stack overlflow` here though. Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: Hm just figured that `update_column(:current_balance, balance)` is the way to go. It's Rails >= v3.1 only though...

Comment: `update_attributes` should work fine - make sure you don't have a recursive method call anywhere (e.g. from a naming collision). You can also try `update_attribute` but that has other implications, so check out the documentation.

Comment: Hmm strange. I still get a `stack level is too deep` error when using `update_attributes`. And I don't have any recursive method calls anywhere. Why can't I use `update_column`? It works like a charme...

Comment: `update_column` doesn't run validations or callbacks. It's fine to use as long as you're aware of that implication.